# html, css: Adjustment height of the table to the number of rows

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="modal-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table id="table">
                   <thead>
                    <tr>
                       <th>...</th>
                           ...
                    </tr>
                   <thead>

                   <tbody>
                    <tr>
                       <td>...</td>
                           ...
                    </tr>
                   <thead>
                 </table> 
              </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to adjust height of the table depending on number of rows. I want to limit the height using some number (N px) but if there are fewer rows (that fill less than N px) the table should be lower. I've tried to set max-height but without success (box was empty then).

Edit:
I've tried:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/569e4msL/)

Comment: Can you include the CSS you tried that gave the empty box result?

Comment: I've just tried to set max-height: 300px  to table tag or .table-responsive class. Also tried to set height, but then it was fixed

Comment: Could you possibly post a complete [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar including the HTML & CSS that don't work? Setting max-height should give the desired behavior.

Comment: @user6808217 set fixed height for each row, so the table height it is multiplied by the row =D

Answer (score 1):

Simply add height to `tr` so the table are multipled by `tr`, also I changed your `id="table"` to `class="mytable"` just for showing the example.

```css
tr {
  height: 50px;
}

table *{
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-responsive{
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>tr here 111111</th>
          <th>tr here 222222</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>tr here 22222</th>
          <td>td here 22222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>tr here 33333</th>
          <td>td here 33333</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>tr here 44444</th>
          <td>td here 44444</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <th>tr here 55555</th>
          <td>td here 55555</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="mytable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>tr here 111111</th>
          <th>tr here 222222</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>tr here 22222</th>
          <td>td here 22222</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the below code,

```css
table,td,th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}

 thead,tbody{
    display:block;
 }
  
tbody{
   max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr> <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr> <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```